# Ring only for favorites?

Tags: ringtone

Any way to micromanage ringtones?  I'd like to only hear my phone ring when called by people on one of my favorite lists, or family list.  Same with sms/mms sounds.

Edit:
I'd already considered putting everyone but favorites on silent.  However those lists change fairly often.  So only a specific group ringing at a specific time is prefered.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. I use Zedge to get ringtones. Get a mute or silent ringtone and then select another ringtone and set it manually for specific people. Zedge also helps you set it for individual contacts.